# Как массив записать на php

Tags: php, массивы

Как такой массив записать на php

```
"Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 1
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 2
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 3
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 4
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 5
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 6
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 7
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 8
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 9
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 10
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 11
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 12
                    [td_class] => NewsCalToday
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 13
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 14
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 15
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 16
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 17
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 18
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 19
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 20
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 21
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 22
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 23
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 24
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 25
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 26
                    [td_class] => NewsCalDefault
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 27
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 28
                    [td_class] => NewsCalWeekend
                    [tday_class] => NewsCalDay
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
"
```

Массив представляет дни месяца разделенные по 7 дней в неделю. Надо преобразовать в массив без деления на недели, просто набор дней сколько их в месяце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо упростить имеющийся массив, то можно сделать

```
$result = array_merge(...$data);
```

в целом если что, генерация массива по числу дней в месяце выглядит как `range(1, date('t'))`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось